# locally finite refinement of a cover of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

I would like to ask about refiniments of a cover of $\mathbb{R}$.(set of real numbers)

Here is a one of well known open cover of $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ where $\tau$ is the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$; $\mathcal{U}^{*}=\{(-n,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

A refinement $\mathcal{V}$ of a cover $\mathcal{U}$ is a new cover if for every $V\in\mathcal{V}$ there exists $U_{V}\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $V\subset U_{V}$.

I would like to ask that "Is every open refinements of the open cover $\mathcal{U}^{*}=\{(-n,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ infinite?"

I think "yes", because if  $\mathcal{U}^{*}$ has a finite open refiniment like $\mathcal{V}^{*}=\{V_{i}: i=1,2,...,n\}$, then for every $V_{i}\in\mathcal{V}^{*}$ there exists $U_{i}\in\mathcal{U}^{*}$ such that $V_{i}\subset U_{i}$ and $\mathcal{V}^{*}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$. If $\mathcal{V}^{*}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ then $\mathcal{U}^{**}=\{U_{i}: i=1,2,...,n\}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{U}^{**}$ is finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}^{*}$. So wouldnt it be a contradiction? Any help or hint will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: But if all this $V_{i}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$, so the supersets $U_{i}$ also covers $\mathbb{R}$? Can you please explain what you stated? I could not yet understand. @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: so, none of open refinements of $\mathcal{U}^{*}$ is finite, right? @SassatelliGiulio